# VBA program not "showing up" on View Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn the basics of `VBA` coding. I copied this code word for word from an Excel course, other than changing the tax rate:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NettoGross(Net As Double)
Dim TaxRate As Double
    TaxRate = 0.01
    NettoGross = Net * (1 + TaxRate)
End Function
```

Yet, when I go to Excel and view macros, it's nowhere to be found. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function won't appear in the View Macros ... only subroutines. As a function is meant to return a value ... so it is used in cells and other places where a standard Excel function would be used.

For example ... go to cell A1 and enter **=NettoGross(1)**.

Comment: It says "ambiguous name detected: NettoGross."

Comment: The error indicates that you've created the same "named" function (ie. NettoGross) twice in your code somewhere(?)

Comment: I tried writing a new code from scratch, and it did work. I can't find that first effort. I guess it vanished. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Public` keyword defines the scope of `Function` and `Sub` routine. Macros dialog shows only `Sub` routines which are either having `Public` or no scope definition prefix before them. Applying `Private` makes it invisible in the macros dialog.

Notably, if there are arguments being passed to a `Public Sub` then that also makes it invisible.
e.g. `Public Sub CalculateGross(Net as Double)` will not be visible through macros dialog.

If you intend to use a `Public Function` (which is also called User Defined Function or UDF) then it can be called like sheet function if it is inserted in a module and not in any `Worksheet` or `ThisWorkbook` module. You can write it like a formula e.g.

`=NettoGross(A1)`

where cell `A1` holds net value to be passed.